# Is pawn promotion obligatory?

Tags: rules, pawns, pawn-promotion

According to Wikipedia, when a pawn advances to the eighth rank, the pawn is promoted as a part of the move.

However, this doesn't make it clear whether I am obliged to promote the pawn if it gets to the eighth rank.

Comment: Promotion itself is not itself a move separate from moving to the eighth rank.  It's all part of a single move.

Comment: I always wanted to know if there is a position where not promoting the pawn is the best move :)

Comment: @Saibot Ask that as a new question and I'll give you an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is obligatory.

From FIDE's Laws of Chess §3.7e ([Link](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=171&view=article)):

> e. When a player, having the move, plays a pawn to the rank furthest from its starting position, he must exchange that pawn as part of the same move for a new queen, rook, bishop or knight of the same colour on the intended square of arrival.

Comment: And note that if he doesn't, it's an illegal move that must be corrected, _and then you are only allowed to choose a queen_. Since july 2014 iirc. People were using the delay to make up their minds. See rule 7.5a.